# Process html content returned from api system in webforms

Tags: api, webforms, httpresponse, html-rendering

I have a MVC webforms project which calls an API system. API system call returns html content which I need to render. Following is my code snippet :

**Implementation of Get Call to api**

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCall()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content =  new StringContent("<html><p>Hello World!!</p></html>");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

    return response;
}
```

I will make this GetCall() function from my aspx.cs code. What I'm not getting is how I can process the html content received in aspx.cs to render the html page (as per the html content returned)

Can anyone pls point out how I can process the html content received on aspx.cs side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what all you're asking, but one easy way to display/render a string of HTML on an aspx page is to use a Literal. Something like this:

aspx:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

cs:

```
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     myLiteral.Text = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

StreamReader here is used to get the response content as a string.